# Unable to run junits in parallel

Tags: java, maven, junit4, surefire

I am using Surefie(2.16) and JUnit(4.11) to run my tests during a maven build (clean install). I call a suite to be executed that contains two suites that i want to be ran in parallel. The problem is that they are not ran in parallel at all. This is my configuration:

```
<profile>
        <id>integrationtests</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <configuration>
                            <parallel>classes</parallel>
                            <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                        </configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/IntegrationTestsSuite.java</include>
                        </includes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

> Below the Suite:

```
    @RunWith(StopOnFirstFailureSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ MachineASuite.class, MachineBSuite.class })
public class IntegrationTestsSuite {

}
```

And here is an example of a class defined in the above suite:

```
@RunWith(StopOnFirstFailureSuite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ Dummy.class })
public class MachineASuite {

}
```

The problem is that the test class Dummy and another test class from MachineBSuite get executed sequentially not parallel.
The command I run is "mvn clean install -P integrationtests" and by judging the output, they are not in parallel. Could you point out what I'm doing wrong, please?

Comment: Do you mean, that on test suite does only work when the othe ris run parallell? Each test suite, and each test case shall run independent on any other, whether or not another test suite runs parallel. Check the docu for the "parallel "feature. Does this mean : they may run parallel, but they are not forced to do so.

Comment: First problem. Why not using maven-failsafe-plugin for integration tests. Furthermore using suites sounds wrong to me. Just use maven-failsafe/surefire to run the test and you need to set `threadCountSuites` to something different than `0` Furthermore don't use the [deprecated marked parameters](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html).

Comment: @AlexWien what im saying is that they do not run in parallel. And yeah, of course the test cases are not dependent, only grouped. Also i couldn't understand your last part